# React + Redux + Storybook: How to use connected react router's useParams when writing storybook stories?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, storybook

I have a react component that grabs an `id` from the route and uses that to load some data and populate the redux state.

I am using `useParams` from 'react-router' to do this.

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router'

import { usePreload } from './hooks'
import Display from './Display'

const Overview = () => {
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { data } = usePreload(id) // uses useEffect to preload the data with the given id

  return <Display data={data} />
}

export default Overview
```

I've got a story

```js
import Overview from './Overview'

import preloadData from './decorators/preloadData'

export default {
  title: 'Redux/scenes/Overview',
  decorators: [preloadData()],
  component: Overview,
  argTypes: {}
}

const Template = args => <Overview {...args} />

export const Default = Template.bind({})
```

The `preloadData` decorator is simply

```js
import { usePreload } from '../hooks'
import { data } from './fixtures'

const Loaded = ({ children }) => {
  useSubmissionsPreload(data.id) // loads the site data into the state

  return <>{children}</>
}

const preloadData = () => Story => (
  <Loaded>
    <Story />
  </Loaded>
)

export default preloadData
```

The code all works fine when actually running in the site but when running within a story there is no `:id` in the path for `useParams` to pick up.

For now I am just going to skip this story and just test the `Display` component, but the completist in me demands to know how to get this to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also had the problem and the comment from De2ev pointed me in the right direction. It did however not work directly and I had to make slight changes. In the end it worked with the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Meta } from "@storybook/react";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";
import { MemoryRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";

export default {
    title: "My Title",
    component: MyComponent,
    decorators: [(Story) => (
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/path/58270ae9-c0ce-42e9-b0f6-f1e6fd924cf7"]}>
            <Route path="/path/:myId">
                <Story />
            </Route>
        </MemoryRouter>)],
} as Meta;

export const Default = () => <MyComponent />;
```

Comment: this gives me the error `A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.`

Comment: That's because you are using v6 — wrap your <Route> in <Routes> and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

I've faced the same problem with Storybook 6.3+ and React Router 6.00-beta and had to wrap the `<Route>` with `<Routes></Routes>` for it to work.

```
import React from "react";
import { Meta } from "@storybook/react";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";
import { MemoryRouter, Routes, Route} from "react-router";

export default {
    title: "My Title",
    component: MyComponent,
    decorators: [(Story) => (
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/path/58270ae9-c0ce-42e9-b0f6-f1e6fd924cf7"]}>
           <Routes>
             <Route path="/path/:myId" element={<Story />}/>
           </Routes>
        </MemoryRouter>)],
} as Meta;

export const Default = () => <MyComponent />;
```

Answer (score 2):

We have faced similar challenge when trying to create storybook for one of the pages. We found solution published on Medium -> [link](https://chestozo.medium.com/how-to-mock-location-inside-storybook-stories-76a7c0705354). All credits and special thanks to the author.

Solution is using [MemoryRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter) available in react-router.

In our solution we used storybook [Decorators](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators) which return the story wrapped by MemoryRouter and Router ->

`return ( <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/routeName/param"]} <Route component={(routerProps) => <Story {...routerProps} />} path="/routeName/:paramName"/>  </MemoryRouter>)`

I hope this helps everyone who experienced the same challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and completed as below

```
export default {
      title: 'Common/Templates/Template Rendering',
      component: CasePage
    }
    //  We create a “template” of how args map to rendering
    const Template: Story<any> = (args: any) => {
      const { path } = args
      return (
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={path}>
          <Route
            component={(routerProps: any) => <CasePage {...routerProps} />}
            path="/dcp/:caseId"
          />
        </MemoryRouter>
      )
    }
    
    export const TemplateBoxesRendering = Template.bind({})
    TemplateBoxesRendering.args = { path: ['/dcp/FX77777'] }
    
    export const TemplateBoxes = Template.bind({})
    TemplateBoxes.args = { path: ['/dcp/FX22222'] }
```